# Javascript - Parsing toDateString Month from a text string to number string using "IF" vs "SWITCH"

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement, switch-statement

I have what is probably a very simple question about using IF statements vs SWITCH in Javascript.  I am attempting to add the current date to my page in the format "Month/Day/Year" where "Month" is a number like so "03/30/2015".  I have been able to solve this problem using the code below: http://jsfiddle.net/mshirk/zre1y20r/

```
var d = new Date();
var dd = d.toDateString();
var ddd = dd.split(' '); 
ddd.shift();    
var mon = ddd[0];
var da = ddd[1];
var yr =ddd[2];
if (mon == "Jan"){monb = 1;}
if (mon == "Feb"){monb = 2;}
if (mon == "Mar"){monb = 3;}
if (mon == "Apr"){monb = 4;}
if (mon == "May"){monb = 5;}
if (mon == "Jun"){monb = 6;}
if (mon == "Jul"){monb = 7;}
if (mon == "Aug"){monb = 8;}
if (mon == "Sep"){monb = 9;}
if (mon == "Oct"){monb = 10;}
if (mon == "Nov"){monb = 11;}
if (mon == "Dec"){monb = 12;}
slashDate = monb + "/" + da + "/" + yr;
document.getElementById('titleDate').innerHTML = slashDate;
```

However, my understanding is that it would be better to use a SWITCH statement here.  So I have replaced the lengthy IF statements with a SWITCH statement as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/mshirk/q0mfds0t/2/

```
var d = new Date();
var dd = d.toDateString();
var ddd = dd.split(' '); 
ddd.shift();    
var mon = ddd[0];
var da = ddd[1];
var yr =ddd[2];
switch(mon){
    case "Jan": monb = 01;
    case "Feb": monb = 02;
    case "Mar": monb = 03;
    case "Apr": monb = 04;
    case "May": monb = 05;
    case "Jun": monb = 06;
    case "Jul": monb = 07;
    case "Aug": monb = 08;
    case "Sep": monb = 09;
    case "Oct": monb = 10;
    case "Nov": monb = 11;
    case "Dec": monb = 12;
}
slashDate = monb + "/" + da + "/" + yr;
document.getElementById('titleDate').innerHTML = slashDate;
```

The problem is that the date produced by the SWITCH statement is wrong!?!?  Can anyone help explain why the date produced by the IF statements is correct and the date produced by the SWITCH statement is incorrect?  Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Why are you parsing the date string instead of using methods like `getDate` and `getMonth`?

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for your help, I actually didnt think to use getDate or getMonth - I guess there are a 1000 ways to skin a cat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need breaks after each case

```
switch(mon){
case "Jan": monb = 01; break;
case "Feb": monb = 02; break;
case "Mar": monb = 03; break;
case "Apr": monb = 04; break;
case "May": monb = 05; break;
case "Jun": monb = 06; break;
case "Jul": monb = 07; break;
case "Aug": monb = 08; break;
case "Sep": monb = 09; break;
case "Oct": monb = 10; break;
case "Nov": monb = 11; break;
case "Dec": monb = 12; break;
}
```

If the break statement isn't provided, then the switch will continue to hit the next case, even if that case does not match the criteria given to the switch.
In this case if no break statements, it would always return 12 for monb.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#What_happens_if_I_forgot_a_break

Comment: You should explain why this is needed.

Answer (score 0):

you need break keyword to skip other conditions

```
  switch(mon){
    case "Jan": monb = 01;break ;
    case "Feb": monb = 02;break ;
    case "Mar": monb = 03;break ;
    ......
```

why  happen to  use break it's C syntax

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162574/why-do-we-have-to-use-break-in-switch

I have a little suggestion to improve your code

```
 var d = new Date();
 var da = d.getDate();
 var monb = d.getMonth()+1;
 var yr = d.getFullYear();

 slashDate = monb + "/" + da + "/" + yr;

 document.getElementById('titleDate').innerHTML = slashDate;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q0mfds0t/3/